# What environment variables are passed to Jenkins when using the Gerrit Trigger Plugin?

Tags: triggers, jenkins, environment-variables, gerrit

I'm using the Gerrit Trigger Plugin to kick off Jenkins builds, but haven't found a good place where all of the environment variables are documented.  Does such documentation exist?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As a start, I had a Jenkins build shell script dump all environment variables with `GERRIT` in the name:

```
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER=\"Alan Thompson\" <theEmail@gmail.com>
GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION=eec3b0b65fcdf30872befa2e9ace06e96cd487b4
GERRIT_CHANGE_ID=Ieec3b0b65fcdf30872befa2e9ace06e96cd487b4
GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER=1
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=theEmail@gmail.com
GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER=8
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER=\"Alan Thompson\" <theEmail@gmail.com>
GERRIT_REFSPEC=refs/changes/08/8/1
GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE=change-merged
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT=\"Alan Thompson\" <theEmail@gmail.com>
GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT=toast:  this is great with coffee
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME=Alan Thompson
GERRIT_PROJECT=kitchen
GERRIT_EVENT_HASH=-1357519550
GERRIT_BRANCH=master
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL=theEmail@gmail.com
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL=theEmail@gmail.com
GERRIT_CHANGE_URL=http://localhost/8
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_NAME=Alan Thompson
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME=Alan Thompson
```

Comment: What did you use to get the output?
When I try to list all the environmental variables of the Jenkins process (from /proc/pid/environ) i don't get those.

Comment: @Alan Likely just a simple execute shell build operation that does `env | grep '^GERRIT'` or similar.

Answer (score 9):

The exact answer can be found in the source [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger/GerritTriggerParameters.java) and there is at least some source code comments describing what it means.

Answer (score 4):

Thank your for your share. I find the [GerritTriggerParameters.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/65135686c9657091dc000af3ee16a1b698742df7/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger/GerritTriggerParameters.java) on GitHub. and I write the shell-script to print the **gerrit-trigger** variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ============================================================
#  Author: 凍仁翔 / chusiang.lai (at) gmail.com
#  Blog: http://note.drx.tw
#  Filename: showGerritTriggerVar.sh
#  Description: show all variables of Gerrit Trigger.
#  Last modified: 2014-08-28 14:40
# =========================================================== 


echo -e "----
# Parameter name for the commit subject (commit message's 1st line).
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT}

# Parameter name for the full commit message.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_COMMIT_MESSAGE = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_COMMIT_MESSAGE}

# Parameter name for the branch.
\$GERRIT_BRANCH = ${GERRIT_BRANCH}

# Parameter name for the topic.
\$GERRIT_TOPIC = ${GERRIT_TOPIC}

# Parameter name for the change-id.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_ID = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_ID}

# Parameter name for the change number.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}

# Parameter name for the URL to the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_URL = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_URL}

# Parameter name for the patch set number.
\$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER = ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}

# Parameter name for the patch set revision.
\$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION = ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}

# Parameter name for the Gerrit project name.
\$GERRIT_PROJECT = ${GERRIT_PROJECT}

# Parameter name for the refspec.
\$GERRIT_REFSPEC = ${GERRIT_REFSPEC}

# The name and email of the abandoner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER}

# The name of the abandoner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER_NAME = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER_NAME}

# The email of the abandoner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_ABANDONER_EMAIL}

# The name and email of the owner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER}

# The name of the owner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME}

# The email of the owner of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL}

# The name and email of the restorer of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER}

# The name of the restorer of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER_NAME = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER_NAME}

# The email of the restorer of the change.
\$GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_CHANGE_RESTORER_EMAIL}

# The name and email of the uploader of the patch-set.
\$GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER = ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER}

# The name of the uploader of the patch-set.
\$GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_NAME = ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_NAME}

# The email of the uploader of the patch-set.
\$GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL}

# The name and email of the person who triggered the event.
\$GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT = ${GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT}

# The name of the person who triggered the event.
\$GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME = ${GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME}

# The email of the person who triggered the event.
\$GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}

# The refname in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_REFNAME = ${GERRIT_REFNAME}

# The old revision in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_OLDREV = ${GERRIT_OLDREV}

# The new revision in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_NEWREV = ${GERRIT_NEWREV}

# The submitter in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_SUBMITTER = ${GERRIT_SUBMITTER}

# The name of the submitter in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_SUBMITTER_NAME = ${GERRIT_SUBMITTER_NAME}

# The email of the submitter in a ref-updated event.
\$GERRIT_SUBMITTER_EMAIL = ${GERRIT_SUBMITTER_EMAIL}

# The name of the Gerrit instance.
\$GERRIT_NAME = ${GERRIT_NAME}

# The host of the Gerrit instance.
\$GERRIT_HOST = ${GERRIT_HOST}

# The port number of the Gerrit instance.
\$GERRIT_PORT = ${GERRIT_PORT}

# The protocol scheme of the Gerrit instance.
\$GERRIT_SCHEME = ${GERRIT_SCHEME}

# The version of the Gerrit instance.
\$GERRIT_VERSION = ${GERRIT_VERSION}

# A hashcode of the Gerrit event object to make sure every set of parameters
# is unique (allowing jenkins to queue duplicate builds).
\$GERRIT_EVENT_HASH = ${GERRIT_EVENT_HASH}

# The type of the event.
\$GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE = ${GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE}
"
```

Comment: Your list is missing `GERRIT_EVENT_COMMENT_TEXT`

Answer (score 4):

Trigger a shell job with just one line:

```
env | grep GERRIT_
```

and see the *Build Log*

Answer (score 4):

Really important information, for anyone who bashed their head against the monitor like I did. There was a security update for Jenkins in May 2016 which doesn't allow arbitrary parameters unless they're defined in the job configuration:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170

The parameters defined by Alan Thompson are correct, but you also need to define those parameters in the job configuration.

Comment: How do I do this? Any links?

Answer (score 3):

They are listed in the help text for the trigger; the little question mark next to the "Gerrit event" trigger checkbox on the job config page.

[image]

Comment: I can find a help button that shows all the possible Gerrit triggers, but not one that shows all possible Gerrit environment variables. Please post a screenshot of the correct button to click.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the answer above. It's the question mark next to "Gerrit event".