# How do I detect that gerrit change needs rebasing on Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, git-review

I want to fail-fast on Gerrit triggered Jenkins jobs when the changes are outdated and they need rebasing by adding a piece of code at the start of the job that triggers and error: "Rebase your change first."

You can find the list of Jenkins variables defined by Gerrit plugin at [What environment variables are passed go Jenkins when using the Gerrit Trigger Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577386/what-environment-variables-are-passed-go-jenkins-when-using-the-gerrit-trigger-p)

Answer (score 0):

This **broken** attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -exo pipefail
# fast-fail if gerrit change is not rebased
if [ -z ${GERRIT_PROJECT+x} ]; then
  pushd $GERRIT_PROJECT
    MERGE_BASE=$(git merge-base HEAD origin/$GERRIT_BRANCH)
    git rebase
    [ "$MERGE_BASE" == "$(git merge-base HEAD origin/$GERRIT_BRANCH)" ] || {
      echo "FATAL:  Please rebase $GERRIT_CHANGE_URL change request before testing it."
      exit 101
    }
  popd
fi
```

Somehow this worked on some jobs using pipelines but failed on others, I suspect due to a different checkout method. So, still looking for a reliable way of doing it.