# How to find out if a Gerrit review is draft or not?

Tags: gerrit

I have a tool that automatically adds reviewers to a Gerrit review. I don't want to add reviewers for draft reviews (created with: `git push origin HEAD:refs/drafts/master`). I have not been able to figure out how to conclude if a review is a draft or not. The Gerrit patchset-created events contains no such info.

What is the best way conclude if a certain review is draft or not?

Comment: To clarify, we use the  Gerrit Trigger Plugin, so the parameter we see are listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577386/what-environment-variables-are-passed-to-jenkins-when-using-the-gerrit-trigger-p

Answer (score 0):

If your Gerrit version is 2.14.x or below:

Look at the IS_DRAFT parameter, which will receive the true (draft) or false (not draft) value.